# how to trigger a python script when a particular software or game is triggered?

Tags: python, automation, background, operating-system, pyautogui

Am playing a game named "Apex Legends".so basically I want to automate my controls for the game using a IMU sensor and pyautogui, pyserial library which would make normal keyboard control into gesture controlled control using IMU sensor and python libraries mentioned.So is there a way that a particular python script should start executing when I start apex legends and stop execution when I terminate apex legends. Hope am clear about my question.

Comment: Cheating is bad! Anyway this site is about help with some problems with real code. Show something you already done and what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact steps but if you're on Windows, you can create a new Task on Windows Task Scheduler that triggers on an Event. To view Windows Events, you can make use of the Windows Event Viewer to find the Event ID that you are looking for.